# Reference error when deploying MVC website on server that imports a .NET standard class with a system.data.sqlclient reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This is my first question. I have tried really hard to find a solution to my problem, but it seems to be a pretty specific collection of problems and I haven't found anything that works. I think I have narrowed down/identified my problem, but I don't know the solution or how to implement it correctly. I have tried to be detailed, but also concise. I don't have a strong coding theory background, just what I have learned online from MS documentation, Stack overflow, and other tutorial-like websites.

**Background**

In visual studio I wanted to create a class library that manages tables in a given database. It's part of a generic style API to handle implementations of repetitive database structures across projects. Because I wanted to create a generic class that I could use in various projects utilising various .NET frameworks, I decided to build the class using .NET standard 1.4. Because I needed to connect to MS SQL databases, I imported the System.Data.SqlClient namespace (an System.Data.Common) using NuGet.

I employed the use of a test MVC application in the solution and got some basic functions working in Visual Studio including opening the actual databases. Despite the recommendation not to, I referenced the compiled DLL from the release build rather than importing the reference as a project. I did this to mimic how I would be testing the class in my deploy environment. Everything here worked fine provided I added the reference to System.Data.SqlClient in the test application.

When testing the deployment however, things went awry. I was using an FTP connection to copy the files to the server. The server is running the .NET 4.5.2 framework. I kept getting a persistent error that the System.Data.SqlClient version 4.1 could not be found. I tried importing it into the project using NuGet and still had the problem. I was importing version 4.1, the earliest version (which is what I referenced in the class library). I also tried changing the reference in the class library to 4.4.2, the latest version, and importing that instead. Still had the same problem.

I then copied the code from the C# class from the class library and added it to a new .cs file in the FTP project- it compiled and ran without incident. I didn't need to import the System.Data.SqlClient in order to reference it, suggesting that a version of the namespace is already available on the server.

**Problem/Question**

This leads me to believe that there is a conflict where I'm trying to reference 2 different versions of System.Data.SqlClient within the FTP project.

As such, this leaves me to try and work out either:

How can I build a .NET standard class library that can use the latest installed version of System.Data.SqlClient in the target project (although, I fell like this is not really achievable given the way DLLs/versioning in general works)?

OR

How can I build a .NET standard class library that can use any of the currently available versions of System.Data.SqlClient (i.e. only use APIs that all current versions implement) and target the one already installed/referenced in the project that references it?

OR

How can I tell visual studio to include the referenced System.Data.SqlClient version used in my standard class library and only reference it for the purposes of running this library, with the rest of the project targeting whatever the other version may be?

OR

The otherwise correct way to manage this reference when it is not in the .NET standard library, but may be present in any given version in the application that references my library DLL.

Basically, I want to avoid having to write a new version of this class for every target framework if I don't have to.

**End Note**

I hope this question is of a good standard, I feel I have probably gone about something wrong in the implementation and that advice on the proper way to implement such a library would be of great help to myself and others in a similar situation.